# is django compressor default on django install?

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-compressor, whitenoise

Is django compressor default on django install?

I have been having an issue with whitenoise and django. I keep getting this error:

`ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'inline.bundle.js'`

now all the research I have done points that it may be a `whitenoise` (im using heroku) and a issue with django compressor. But I do not remember installing such a tech. Is it by default? One of the work arounds suggested is to replace django compressor with another. But how?

Actively researching this, if anyone has had this issue before would appreciate a work around.

Comment: That _looks_ like an Angular issue. And no, `django-compressor` is not installed by default unless it is installed by a third party library.

Comment: @Selcuk I thought i was too. So I created a new app and copied all my html css and ts files over. Rebuilt the app, and I still have this issue. I can run the app locally, I can run the api part of my heroku server and serve the angular app on my local server and have them talk to each other no problem. Its only when I try to run angular room my local api server, or heroku that I have this problem and it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

This problem belong to angular2/4/5. If you are using angular2/4/5 then it will come because you forget to upload inline script in index.html of python's project.

please add this in `index.html` file of python's project templates

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ANGULAR_STATIC}}inline.bundle.js"></script>`

In `setings.py` **ANGULAR_STATIC = 'http://localhost:4200/'**

You can change url according to you.

Comment: Thank you @Razia but I am acutally using angular 6 and this is a new issue that I didn't have before. This is also happening when I run on heroku or from my local django server, not my local angular server. I am not sure you and I are on the same page?